# Matlab: ODE with unusual initial conditions

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, numerical, ode

I am trying to solve differential equation numerically:

```
y'' + a * y * sin(x) + b * y = 0
```

with initial conditions:

```
y(0) = 0
y'(0) = y'(1)
```

But there are only simple initial conditions in examples. And I can't use solvers like `ode45`.

Is there any way to solve differential equation with such initial condition?

Comment: why u can't use ode45?

Comment: This is not an IVP, it is a BVP, so look up the BVP documentation e.g http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/boundary-value-problems.html and convert your problem to first order in the usual way